# Maximum profit sum path with bounded cost in 2d arrays

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming, graph-theory

Given two 2d matrices of size n*n, one is the cost matrix and the other is the profit matrix. We have to find a path from top left (0,0) to bottom right (n-1,n-1) that has the maximum sum of profits and the sum of costs must be less than or equal to C. We can only traverse either right or down.
Constraints n<=100.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: OK, tag shows that you know about DP. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I don't know how to solve the problem. No I haven't tried DP, I thought it was similar to 0/1 knapsack so I tagged DP. I couldn't figure out how to approach the problem.

Comment: What is the intended complexity? Also, what have you tried?  Those are details that should be included in the questions.

Comment: How about constraints of C?

Comment: How would you solve this if there was no cost constraint?

Comment: Actually cost is a floating point integer<1. So C<100.

Comment: Have you solved similar problem without C limit?

Comment: What is a floating point integer? That is like saying a rational irrational number. If you mean floating point number, what would be the precision of it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Calculate the total cost of every path
2. Remove all paths with total cost > C
3. Select remaining path with maximum profit

Note that since n < 100 there are a maximum of 10,000 cells and from each cell there are exactly 2 possible paths, the maximum number of paths is only 20,000.

If max n was significantly greater you would need to look for a more efficient algorithm, but for these small problems this algorithm is sufficient, straightforward and easy to implement.

Comment: "from each cell there are exactly 2 possible paths" This is not *quite* true. There are two (or fewer) *edges* that point out from each cell, but this has little to do with the number of paths.

Answer (score 0):

Subtract the cost matrix to the profit matrix.

This way you have only one matrix and you can now use Floyd-Warshall Algorithm to find the shortest path on a weighted path.

You can use Floyd-Warshall with graph = -G (Assuming there aren't positive values if the graph is inverted, which could happen if for some node revenue-cost = -X , it won't work). This is equivalent to finding the longest simple path.

Comment: So how do you factor C in it?

Comment: cost and profit are totally different things, doing subtraction on them is absolutely meaningless.

Comment: @LearningMathematics i was assuming he was referring to profit as revenue (Which isn't the same thing, but it seems in this case its used interchangeably), but revenue minus cost will give you the right value for each vertex/edge on a graph. Can you give a better explanation on why its not the case please?

Comment: OP didn't state it explicitly, but the problem remains the same whether or not profit can cancel cost anyway, so I assume you don't really need to do that. (Considering the problem looks like it's from a programming contest). Either way, as n 1.8e9 mentioned, your solution doesn't factor C in it.

Comment: @LearningMathematics Could he use DFS to trim the graph from all forbidden paths (Paths that surpass the cost C)? It could reduce the complexity of having to find ALL the paths from (0,0) to (n-1,n-1) . Of course if too many paths have a cost bellow C it becomes hard . Maybe going for a k shortest path for cost first, then floyd-warshall for profit.

Comment: @Souza There exists a simple O(n * n * k) dynamic programming solution where k is the number of possible sum of cost . But it really depends on how large k really is. OP didn't mention it.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I forgot that bit. Maybe using DFS to trim all the bad paths, if C is low enough to provide a feasible solution and the cost distribution is uniform enough between edges (Too many constraints i know). Other approach would be to calculate "k shortest paths" for cost first with every sum bellow C

Comment: @Souza The worst case of your program is basically the same as ravenspoint's algorithm, which is quite large as explained in the comments below.

Comment: @LearningMathematics , not quite. Calculating all paths , is not the same as calculating the paths with a cost lower than C. It really depends on the cost matrix and cost distribution. Are you referring to the solution using DFS or the "k-shortest paths" for cost?

Comment: @Souza I am talking about a **worst case scenario**, where every cost is higher than C.  As the problem appears to be from a programming contest, it is highly unlikely the intended solution is a heuristic algorithm.